# How to read file from network path?

Tags: java

Basic explanation:
I'm coding a simple java utility which will take xml file and convert it into html. All xml files have same structure and need to be converted into same looking HTML file so i chose to code it using BufferedReader and Writer, see code below.

**I'm having following problem** If i'm using file that is on local disk, than there is no problem and everything workes fine, but when i try to use file that is on connected shared network disk, code throws exception.

**this is whole code**

reading and writting file that is stored in project folder workes just fine and just as i want to, i'm only having problem with file stored on network disk.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String cestaKsuboruXml = "file.xml"; //workes fine

    //this one throws error
   // String cestaKsuboruXml = "\\172.27.20.38\eDesk\2017\0925\144f7d8d-3786-4858-95ef-bb853c41b713\1_PridelenieCislaPodania.xml"; 

         //class which contains html code
        sablonaJedna sablonaJedna = new sablonaJedna();

        String fileName = null ;

        String line = null;

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder subject = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(cestaKsuboruXml);

            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(cestaKsuboruXml), "UTF-8"));

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                if (line.contains("<subject>")) {
                    subject.append(line);
                }

                if (!line.contains("<GeneralAgenda") && !line.contains("<subject>"))

                {
                    text.append(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }


        String text2 = text.toString();
        String subject2 = subject.toString();

        subject2 = subject2.replace("<subject>", "");
        subject2 = subject2.replace("</subject>", "");
        text2 = text2.replace("<text>", "");
        text2 = text2.replace("</text>", "");
        text2 = text2.replace("</GeneralAgenda>", "");






        try {
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter
                    (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("vvvaa.html", true), "UTF-8"));

            writer.write(sablonaJedna.getSablonaCss() + sablonaJedna.getSablonaHtml() + subject2 +
                    "</span></div><div class=\"clear\"> </div><div><label class=\"labelVis\">Text: </label> <span class=\"contentVis wordwrap\">"
                    + text2 + "</span></div><div class=\"clear\"> </div></div></div></body></html>"
            );

            writer.close();

        } catch (IOException xx) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
        }

}
```

Comment: How do you want to access this disk?  Have you, or do you intend to, mapped it to a network drive?  If not, what protocol do you want to use to access it?  SAMBA? FTP? There is nowhere near enough information here to be able to answer your question.

Comment: i already have access to this disk i have read and write rights to it

Comment: Add the error message and stacktrace, please.

Comment: Unrelated: Why hardcode all this, when you can use [xsl Transformation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html)?

Answer (score 1):

all i had to do was use this as a source:

```
String cestaKsuboruXml = "\\\\172.27.20.38\\eDesk\\2017\\0925\\144f7d8d-3786-4858-95ef-bb853c41b713\\1_PridelenieCislaPodania.xml";
```

so two more backslashes at the start of a link

Comment: The network path is `\\host\folder\subfolder`... but you have to escape backslash in quotes, that is the reason why it needs to be doubled, in case of `\\172.27.20.38\\eDesk\\2017\\0925\\...` it got interpreted like `\172.27.20.38\eDesk\2017\0925\..` which is not correct path, obviously